# How do I pass an array from one form to another?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows

I'm coding in c#.

I am creating an array of objects in the first form.

I want to open up a second form that displays the information in the array in a listbox.

How do I pass the information in the array in the first form to a new array in the second form?

Edit:

This is the code I have in the first form.

```
f2.F2People = people;
```

F2People is the properties of the f2people array in the second form. (the array is private, so you would use the properties to set a value). people is the array in the first form. I have this code inside the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the constructor of the second form, pass in your array, and store it in a variable. Then during the form load event of form two, load your list box.

Comment: I have added a little more information to the original question.

Comment: That looks OK, but obviously f2.F2People needs to be public.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered something similar at

[Passing data between forms on form closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747378/passing-data-between-forms-on-form-closing/18753443#18753443)

if this works for you I can easily ports this to C#.